# navigationItem titleview align center between buttons

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I have the code likes, in the title bar I am having 3 buttons, left search button, right camera button and option button, in between I am having title.

What I want to do is, I want to display the title centered between the search button and Camera button, can anyone help me how to do this.

```
//Left Button
UIBarButtonItem *leftSearch = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_search"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(gotoSearch)];

leftSearch.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -5.0f, 0, 0);

[leftSearch setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
/////////

//Right Button -- First Camera
UIBarButtonItem *rightCamera = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_camera"]
                                style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                target:self
                                action:@selector(gotoPhotoGallery)];
[rightCamera setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
rightCamera.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, -59.0f);
///////////////////

//Right second Button -- for options menu
UIBarButtonItem *rightMenu = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header_option"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(gotoPhotoGallery)];
[rightMenu setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
rightMenu.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 5.0f);
///////////////////

NSArray *buttons = @[rightMenu, rightCamera];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttons;

[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:leftSearch];

//Title Label

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo Sans" size:20];
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.text = LoginUserName;
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
[label sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your title label with the same width and height as the navigation bar. For example

```
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width,44)];
titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
titleLabel.text = LoginUserName;
titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:titleLabel];
```

This will put your text in the middle.

Comment: I want title centre between Search button and Camera button, at present my title is close to Search button or sometime it is close to Camera button, due to that title does not looks good.

Comment: I've amended my answer as above. Hopefully this is more useful to you.